# Correct way to concisely identify items using the order in which they were submitted

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

I'm looking for a concise way to say some thing like

> The item that was submitted for first|second|third|...

The best I could come up with was

> The first|second|third|... submitted item

I guess it's short enough, but I'm not sure it feels natural.

Note that the items are submitted in a batch, but in an ordered fashion.
Also,  "first|second|third" are alternatives.

Comment: The question here is: is there a number of times something had to be submitted or not? "The item first submitted was wrong." "The item subsequently submitted was right". "The item submitted the second or third time around was wrong."

Comment: @Lambie No, the items are submitted at the same time. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ahhhhh. "Submitted item numbers 1, 2 and 3 are in the list." OR "Items numbers 1, 2 and 3 were submitted in the batch". first, second and third is probably wrong here for your purpose.

Comment: You could, but why not "The item submitted first|second|third|..."?

Comment: I don't know whether you are proposing to use "first|second|third" in your resulting sentence, or whether you are presenting them as alternatives now, to be instantiated in the resulting sentence. If the former, then there is NO standard interpretation for "first|second|third".

Comment: @ColinFine "first|second|third" are alternatives. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @user3169 I can't really tell the difference but if you're positive that "The item submitted first|second|third|..." feels more natural than "The first|second|third|... submitted item", or if the latter is plainly wrong, I suggest you add this as an answer. At the moment I don't see why I shouldn't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the items were submitted at the same time, and you simply want to identify them by a sequence number, then the clearest way to express this would be:

> The first of the submitted items
>   The second of the submitted items
>   etc